# How to make term frequency matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am working on a sentiment analysis problem, I have to prepare a document frequency matrix. For example, I have three words(data) with the sentiment

He is a good person  | Positive Sense

He is bad student    | Negative Sense

He is hardworking    | Positive Sense

There are the following words in the unique vocabulary.

He,is,a,good,person,bad,student,hardworking

Based on the vocabulary and data I will have 3X8 Matrix given bellow

For 1st sentence: 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0

For 2nd sentence: 1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0

For 3rd sentence: 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1

Please suggest any best and efficient way to achieve this in python.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question with `machine-learning`, I suggest you use [sklearn.CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus = ['He is a good person',
          'He is bad student',
          'He is hardworking']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=corpus, columns=['sentences'])

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=['he', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'person', 'bad', 'student', 'hardworking'], min_df=0,
                             stop_words=frozenset(), token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b")
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['sentences'].values)
result = pd.DataFrame(data=X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   he  is  a  good  person  bad  student  hardworking
0   1   1  1     1       1    0        0            0
1   1   1  0     0       0    1        1            0
2   1   1  0     0       0    0        0            1
```

Comment: What if without this library? further can you please suggest if I have a document with Words marked positive or negative how to convert this document to turn frequency matrix.?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the format of the document?

Comment: Document have two collumn one is the sentiment and other is the word from which i want to prepare the term document.

Answer (score 1):

This is `get_dummies` problem , for achieve what you need you just need follow by `reindex`

```
s='He,is,a,good,person,bad,student,hardworking'.split(',')
df.W1.str.get_dummies(sep=' ').reindex(columns=s)
Out[914]: 
   He  is  a  good  person  bad  student  hardworking
0   1   1  1     1       1    0        0            0
1   1   1  0     0       0    1        1            0
2   1   1  0     0       0    0        0            1
```

---

Data input

```
                    W1               W2
0  He is a good person     Positive Sense
1  He is bad student       Negative Sense
2  He is hardworking       Positive Sense
```

Comment: What will happen if there are duplicated words in the sentence?

Comment: @DanielMesejo will return 1